# c++: Avoid duplicate code during member function full specialization

Tags: c++, template-specialization, specialization, partial-specialization

Code: sorry for java style:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<class K>
class Bundle {
    std::map<K, void *> mValueMap;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void put(K, const T& value) {
        std::cout << "put all, except std::string" << std::endl;
    };
};

template<>
template<>
void Bundle<const char*>::put<std::string>(const char* key, const std::string& value) { //duplicate code
    std::cout << "duplicate code:put std::string" << std::endl;
}

template<>
template<>
void Bundle<int>::put<std::string>(int key, const std::string& value) { //duplicate code
    std::cout << "duplicate code:put std::string" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Bundle<int> intBundle;
    Bundle<const char *> bundle;

    intBundle.put<float>(1, 45.0); // good
    bundle.put<float>("key", 45.0); // good

    intBundle.put<std::string>(1, std::string{}); // not good - duplicate code
    bundle.put<std::string>("key", std::string{}); // not good - duplicate code
}
```

I could only think of such working methods of specialization.
Is it possible (using partial specialization or other methods) to get rid of code duplication.

Comment: There is no code duplication in your program. The code for specialization for `int` and `const char*` is different.

Comment: I update code !!

Comment: Ok, i see......

Comment: You can put the duplicate code inside a function and then call that function from inside the specializations?

Comment: `intBundle.put<std::string>(1, {});` should work too

Comment: Thanks guys, I already moved the duplicated code into a separate function. OK. This is an option. But I also, in view of my inexperience, assume that there may be other options?

Comment: @ilw The only other option I can think of right now is to use macros. Don't :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of full specialization, you might use `if constexpr` (C++17):

```
template<class K>
class Bundle {
    std::map<K, void *> mValueMap;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void put(K, const T& value) {
        if constexpr((std::is_same_v<K, const char*> && std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
            || (std::is_same_v<K, int> && std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)) {
            std::cout << "put std::string" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "put all, except std::string" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: very interesting

Comment: What are the disadvantages, if I will try using `std::is_same_v` without `if constexpr` ? It is just runtime condition?

Comment: @ilw: With [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if), body of each branch not taken is discarded. so you might use methods/code specific to the taken branch (as `value.size()`). With regular `if`, all branches should be valid even if not taken. For performance, chances are optimizer would avoid the computation for the runtime case also.

Answer (score 1):

Whether its code in a specialization or elsewhere, the first measure to fight code duplication is functions:

```
void do_common_thing() {
    std::cout << "duplicate code:put std::string" << std::endl;
}
```

Then call this function in the specializations of your template.

Answer (score 1):

> I could only think of such working methods of specialization. Is it possible (using partial specialization or other methods) to get rid of code duplication.

The simplest(staightforward) way that I can think of is by putting your duplicate code into a separate function and then call that function from inside the specializations.

Something like:

```
void dupeCode()
{
    //duplicate code put here
    std::cout << "duplicate code:put std::string" << std::endl;
}
```

Then you can call the above function from inside the specializations:

```
template<>
template<>
void Bundle<const char*>::put<std::string>(const char* key, const std::string& value) { 
    dupeCode();
}

template<>
template<>
void Bundle<int>::put<std::string>(int key, const std::string& value) { 
    dupeCode();
}
```

Comment: That's what I did, but I thought there was a smarter way :)

Comment: @ilw This method is not "not smart". Often(like here) the simplest way is the best way to go. I mean *"we should write code that is simplest to understand instead of writing code that looks smarter and is hard to read/understand"*.

Comment: I understand. I just wanted to consider all the options - and then draw a conclusion.

Comment: @ilw Yeah that's also good. And maybe someone will suggest a new solution that is different from using a function.